# How can i remove items from microfeed list

Tags: sharepoint-server, newsfeed

How can i remove items from microfeed list?
When i try to remove items there it says

> access denied

I have farm admin priviledges and i am as admin in User Profile Service Application.

Newsfeed gives error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

and there is one empty entry in that microfeed list which is created there on the same date that the problem started so that is the most probable cause.

I don't know how the empty entry has been created but i'm guessing there is no null check for empty content.

Comment: Please, check the ULS log for the acces denied error and post the detailed log

Answer (score 2):

I managed to remove the items from microfeed list that were causing the error with console application by impersonating system account:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SPUserToken sysToken = null;
    using (var spSite = new SPSite("http://siteurl"))
    {
        sysToken = GetSystemToken(spSite);

        using (var impersonatedSite = new SPSite("http://siteurl", sysToken))
        {
            using (var web = impersonatedSite.OpenWeb("weburl"))
            {
                var list = web.Lists["Microfeed"];
                var item = list.GetItemById(itemid);
                item.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
}

protected static SPUserToken GetSystemToken(SPSite spSite)
{
    SPUserToken res = null;
    bool oldCatchAccessDeniedException = spSite.CatchAccessDeniedException;
    try
    {
        spSite.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
        res = spSite.SystemAccount.UserToken;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (var elevatedSPSite = new SPSite(spSite.ID))
            res = elevatedSPSite.SystemAccount.UserToken;
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        spSite.CatchAccessDeniedException = oldCatchAccessDeniedException;
    }
    return res;
}
```